# Select in multiples tables PSQL without join

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, request, multi-table

(Please correct my if i do some mistakes)

I have 2 tables:

- ***ACTIVITIES*** : ID / NAME / CONTENT / DATE /ETC..
- ***ARTICLES*** : ID / NAME /CONTENT /DATE /ETC..

I have created one script to delete image when it is not in the db , the problem is : 
I don't know how to check the content of activity and article on the same request because this request bellow just delete my activities images..

```
#!/bin/bash

db="intranet_carc_development"
user="benjamin"

echo "DELETING UNUSED FILES AND IMAGES..."
for f in public/uploads/files/*
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]
  then
    f="$(basename "$f")"
    psql $db $user -t -v "ON_ERROR_STOP=1" \
    -c "select content from public.articles where content like '%$f%'" | grep . \
    && echo "exist" \
    || rm public/uploads/files/$f
  fi
done
printf "DONE\n\n"
```

If tied something like :

```
select content from public.articles, public.activities where content like '%$f%'"
```

but I have this log **error**:

```
ERROR:  column reference "content" is ambiguous
```

Comment: Both tables have field named content.  You have to specify which one in your where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
WITH artcontent AS (
    SELECT content
    FROM public.articles
),
actcontent AS (
    SELECT content
    FROM public.activities
),
merge AS (
    SELECT * FROM artcontent 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM actcontent 
)
SELECT *
FROM merge
```

The UNION ALL statement will put together your two results artcontent (which comes from articles) and actcontent (from activities).

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Actually Working Thanks